# Do citizens of Switzerland need a visa to travel to Argentina?

Tags: visas, argentina, swiss-citizens

I am a Swiss citizen and will be traveling to Argentina for 2 weeks. I would like to know if I will require a visa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, as a Swiss citizen you do not need a visa for visits up to 90 days.

References: [Official Argentinean Immigration (Spanish)](http://www.migraciones.gov.ar/accesible/indexN.php?visas), [TIMATIC](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=CH&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=AR&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Swiss_citizens#Visa_requirements)

Comment: Thank you very much! I searched admin.ch but could not find anything.

Comment: @zeropaper: in general, it's up to each country to decide who is allowed in (and whether they need a visa, etc.) so you're more likely to find this out from a website of the Argentine government than the Swiss government (in this case http://www.migraciones.gov.ar/accesible/index_mobile.php?visas)